# representative matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this two questions:

1. given a linear transformation: $T:M_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $T(A)=A-2A^T$, what is the representative matrix on this transformation with the standart base.
2. Let $T: \mathbb{F}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^2$ a linear tranformation such that $T^2=0$, Prove that $T=0$, or there exists a basis of $M_2(\mathbb{F})$ in which the representative matrix is: $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Very related question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610568/how-prove-this-matrix-sigma-characteristic-polynomial-fx-x1nx-5-fr/610579#610579

Comment: In question 2, it should be $T\colon\mathbb{F}^2\to\mathbb{F}^2$, probably.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

For the first question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610568/how-prove-this-matrix-sigma-characteristic-polynomial-fx-x1nx-5-fr/610579#610579) a very related question as *Ewan Delanoy* said.

For your second question assume that $T\ne0$ then there's $u\in\Bbb F^2$ such that $T(u)=v\ne0$. Prove that $\mathcal B=(v,u)$ is a basis of $\Bbb F^2$ and the matrix of $T$ in this basis has the desired form.